# Windows UAC, Admin prompt, Run Application with current user rights

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, registry, uac

I want to use a Application on Windows 7 without Admin priviliges.
(Sure for the install process i used Admin priviliges)

Now i had following problem:
When i want to start the application the UAC popup ask for an Admin Account to run the program. But the User had no Admin account and can only click "No" so the Application is closed.

**Is it possible to use this application with the rights from the current user and deactivate the UAC prompt?**

On Win XP, only popup a error message that the application had no admin priviliges.
But by selecting "Ok" the application is starting and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to create and embed a manifest into your application.** This tells the operating system that your program was written to be compatible with the UAC built into Windows Vista (and later), and therefore does not need to be run as Administrator. Set the requested execution level to `asInvoker`.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

There's also a helpful, though somewhat more general, article that appeared in the MSDN Magazine regarding UAC: [Teach Your Apps To Play Nicely With Windows Vista User Account Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have not build this application. I want only that the application run with currentuser account.

Comment: @LaPhi: If you didn't write the application, it's entirely possible that whoever did embedded a manifest with the requested execution level set to `requireAdministrator`. That means it will require Administrator privileges each time the application is executed. There's nothing you can do to change that. Without any more information, there's not much here to go on.